How to Implement Cell Execution Control and JavaScript Alerts in Azure Databricks Notebooks?
I am trying to replicate some functionalities in Azure Databricks notebooks that I previously used in Jupyter notebooks, specifically related to controlling the visibility of notebook cells and showing JavaScript alerts and executing cells within the notebook. Below are three code snippets that work perfectly in Jupyter but not in Databricks:
Example 1:
from IPython.display import HTML, Javascript, display as IPyDisplay, clear_output

HTML('''
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function code_toggle(){
            if (code_shown){
                $('div.input').hide('500');
                $('#toggleButton').val('Show Code')
            } 
            else {
                $('div.input').show('500');
                $('#toggleButton').val('Hide Code')
            }
            code_shown = !code_shown
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            code_shown=false;
            $('div.input').hide()
        });
    </script>
    <form action="javascript:code_toggle()">
        <input type="submit" id="toggleButton" value="Show Code">
    </form>
''')

Example 2:
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

display(Javascript("""
alert('Hello, this is a JavaScript alert!');
"""))

Example 3:
display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_cell_range(IPython.notebook.get_selected_index()+1, IPython.notebook.ncells())'))

These snippets help in toggling the visibility of code cells and in displaying JavaScript alerts in Jupyter. However, when I try to implement similar functionalities in Azure Databricks, they do not work because Databricks doesn't seem to support the same level of integration with JavaScript and HTML that Jupyter does.
Question:
Is there any alternative or method to implement such functionalities in Azure Databricks? Specifically, I am looking for a way to:
Control the visibility of cells in a Databricks notebook.
Execute cells by cell_id within the same notebook.
Trigger JavaScript alerts or other client-side JavaScript functionalities within the Databricks environment.
Any help or guidance on how to achieve this in Azure Databricks would be greatly appreciated!

what is the error you are getting?

The error I receive is:
JavaScript output is disabled in JupyterLab

Yeah. purpose fully the alert is blocked.

Is there no way to re-enable it? Or find something else that substitutes Javascripts functionalities for these purposes?

I guess javascript code doesn't execute.

First, the JavaScript alerts don't work, and that is because of the iframe sandbox configuration. To enable alerts, the sandbox attribute in iframe should have allow-modals.
See the example below; this is purposely not allowed by Databricks.

Next, you can run scripts to customize the visibility of cell results, as mentioned in this sample code in D3 visualizations. But in your case, the form submission redirects to the URL instead of executing the script.
To toggle, you don't need a form tag; just use input like below.
displayHTML('''
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function code_toggle(){
            if (code_shown){
                $('div.input').hide('500');
                $('#toggleButton').val('Show Code')
            } 
            else {
                $('div.input').show('500');
                $('#toggleButton').val('Hide Code')
            }
            code_shown = !code_shown
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            code_shown=false;
            $('div.input').hide()
        });
    </script>
    <input type="button" id="toggleButton" onclick="code_toggle()" value="Show code"></input>
''')

Next, to run the cell by id, you can use dbutils by passing the cell id. Refer to this Stack Overflow solution for more information.
Here, I am just calling the notebook once; you can do it in a loop for a range of cells to be executed.
As of now, the above solutions are possible for your problem and your 2nd and 3rd example simply just return object and doesn't execute it, only use displayHTML
with <script></script> element in html string.

@9879ypxkj Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?
